# Convergence rate of cardinal series

Tags: convergence-divergence, interpolation

Given $f \in C^{\infty}_{0}[a, b]\cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, what can we say about the convergence rate of the cardinal series
$$
s(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(a+jh) \mathrm{sinc}\left(\pi\left(\frac{t-a}{h} -j \right)\right)
$$
to $f$ as $h\to 0$?

Comment: Do you have a relation like $hn = b-a$? ... or do we imagine that the sample points $a + j h$ collapse into the left endpoint of the interval $[a,b]$ as $h \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @EricTowers: Sorry, yes: $hn = b-a$.

Comment: @EricTowers: Fixed

Comment: I see you are putting $\pi$ into your $\mathrm{sinc}$.  There are two standard definitions of $\mathrm{sinc}$: $\mathrm{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $\mathrm{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$.  I'm guessing you are using the first.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.